# How to connect to local react app from another PC from same network?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

How I can connect to my react-app from another PC, but we are in the same network? I just wan't to show the website which I'm making on my colleague PC, cause he is going to use it after it, how I can do it? Or is there any good way to deploy it locally somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me

> Simply run HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start.

get IP of your host PC by using **ifconfig** command

> Afterwards open the url from another device on the network.

Comment: I tried doing like that, buy my page is just loading but never loads.

Comment: @Hexycode You can try this also HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start  instead of HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start

Comment: @Hexycode for setting host environment variable this link is helpful    
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create-react-app`, you could use `HOST` environment variable, like this:

`$ HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start` instead of `npm start`

Then you can access the website on the other computer's IP like `192.x.x.x:3000`

Other than this, you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) which will create your `localhost:3000` public to other computers with a specific link.

Comment: The page is loading but never loads at the end. I'm going to see ngrok or localtunnel ways.